# Fast way to check if page is online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using `Nokogiri` for parsing `XML`.

Problem is in response time of external resource. Sometimes it works fine. Sometimes respond time can be over 30 seconds. Sometimes it returns different error codes. What I need is to find out the fastest way to know if my XML is ready to be requested by `open-uri`. And only then to make actual request.

What I am doing now is setting Timeout to 5 seconds to prevent delays.

```
begin
  Timeout::timeout(5) do 
    link = URI.escape("http://domain.org/timetable.xml")
    @doc  = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  @error = "Data Server is offline"
end
```

Comment: If the service is working, but will take 30 seconds, do you consider that "ready to be requested" or not ready? (Maybe explicitly define your readiness condition.)

Comment: technically yes. But there is no possibility to know how long will take my response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checks at the level your code shows, you'll need cooperation from the remote service, e.g., conditional HEAD requests and/or Etag comparison (those together would be my own preference.) It looks like you may have some of this as you say it sometimes returns error codes, though if the those error codes are in the XML payload they're not going to help and of course, if the remote service's responsiveness is variable it will probably fluctuate between your check and subsequent main GET request.

FWIW: if you're just looking to improve your app's responsiveness when using this data, there are cache approaches you can use, e.g., use a soft-TTL lower than the main TTL that, when expired, causes your cache code to return the cached XML and kick off an async job to refetch the data so it's fresher for the next request. Or use a repeating worker to keep the cache fresh.

Comment: I can't configure external server. And I am using caching :). In my situation it is quite helpful